# Display status on Wix Bootstrap App when extracting

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a Wix toolset Bootstrap application that works great delivering my program's install and a required device dll. When it is ran it can take a while to unpackage the device dll, the first object, and run it. It looks like the Bootstrap package is not working when we know it is.

Is there a way to show a status to the end user that it is running?

Like show the files being extracted or a percent extracted complete?

My Bootstrap below.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
       
  <!--DO NOT TOUCH THE UpgradeCode!!!!!-->
 <Bundle Name="My Programm Installer" Version="1.2.0.0" Manufacturer="My, Co." UpgradeCode="xxxxxx-xxx-x--x-x--xxx">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" >
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
            LicenseFile="My License Agreement.rtf"
            ShowVersion="yes"
            LogoFile="My Logo1.png"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>      
            
    <Chain>
      <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
      <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->
      <PackageGroupRef Id="DeviceDll"/>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="MyProgram"/>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>

  <Fragment>
    <PackageGroup Id="DeviceDll">
      <ExePackage Id="DeviceDll"
          Cache="yes"
          Compressed="yes"
          PerMachine="yes"
          Permanent="yes"
          Vital="no"
          SourceFile="DeviceDll_Setup.exe" />
    </PackageGroup>

    <PackageGroup Id="MyProgram">
      <MsiPackage Id="MyProgram"
          Cache="yes"
          Compressed="yes"
          Permanent="no"
          Vital="yes"
          SourceFile="MyProgram.msi"/>
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

**Edit**
I am using Visual Studio 2017 with the Wix Toolset installed, and I am using the v3 Bootstrap Project. I used v3 over v4 since I could find an example that gave me a working Bootstrap.

Comment: Bundles aren't self-extracting executables. Check the bundle log to see what's happening when the pause happens.

Comment: @BobArnson, I was able to capture the bundle log. It looks to be "Creating a system restore point" that is taking a long time to do. The time that it takes is not what concerns me, it is the display not doing anything for a long period of time. I would like to just display that it is doing something, e.g. route the log messages to the display so the end user can see that the package is doing something.

Comment: @Bluto Maybe check my comment below to Arnson. There seems to be a similar WiX issue open.

Answer (score 0):

`WixStandardBootstrapperApplication` shows `Initializing...` while all the various "startup" stuff happens, before individual packages are installed. Burn doesn't expose an event for the system restore point creation.

Comment: Bob, not a 100% match with the OP's question, but somewhat related: [MSIFASTINSTALL](https://serverfault.com/a/594661/20599) works to suppress a restore point for standalone MSI files. I assume the WiX bundle itself makes the restore point, so it does not help to set [MSIFASTINSTALL](https://serverfault.com/a/594661/20599) per MSI to prevent the system restore point? I see only [Issue 4626](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4626) in WiX issues related to system restore.

Comment: OK, so the bundle sets that for all MSI setups then, unless the setup itself has a value for MSIFASTINSTALL defined in the property table or an associated transform?

Comment: @BobArnson, I am not getting the Initializing... displayed on my package when installing. It would be nice if I did.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul, it's set at build time, so transforms aren't considered.

Comment: @Bluto, please post a screen shot. The string is present, unless you've overridden the loc string.

Comment: @BobArnson, sorry I am wrong. It does show the Initializing..., but sometimes it will sit there up to 10mins before starting the installs.

Comment: So the Initializing... displays while all the various "startup" stuff is happening. Does the Burn tool set expose the logging strings? Can those strings be redirected to the display?

Comment: @Bluto, no, that's the root of the issue Stein linked to earlier.

Comment: Alright. So right now there is nothing more I can do until there is a change to the toolset.